# how to use the remapping syntax

Tags: ros, namespace, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From some of the other question I realized it is possible to remap the namespace of node on the command  line using rosrun. But it is not working for me..

The syntax i tried is ,

```
rosrun somepkg somenode:="new_namespace/somenode.py"
```

and many other variations of it.

Could someone please tell me what is the correct way to remap a node to another name space on the command line while using rosrun?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28903/how-to-use-the-remapping-syntax/) by [cassander](https://answers.ros.org/users/1815/cassander/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2012-03-01

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can only use remapping arguments (the `:=` syntax) for parameters and topics. If you want to push a node into a namespace on the command-line, you would do it like so:

```
$ ROS_NAMESPACE=new_namespace rosrun somepkg somenode
```

This will force `somenode` to be in the `new_namespace` namespace.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2012-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Look at: http://www.ros.org/wiki/Remapping%20Arguments

I'm not sure if you maybe want to only change the `__name` but not the namespace.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-03-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cassander](https://answers.ros.org/users/1815/cassander/) on 2012-03-02**:
actually.. im looking to only change the namespace.. Maybe that is why the command I tried did not work..